# relation between p-sylow subgroups

Tags: group-theory

let $G$ be a group of order divisible by $p,q$.
for any $p$-sylow subgroup $P$ and $q$-sylow subgroup $Q$.
I know the intersection $P\cap Q = \{e\}$ because the orders are different.
what about two $p$-sylow subgroups, can I say their intersection is only $e$?

thanks.
benny.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24704/simple-group-theory-question-regarding-sylow-theorems).

Comment: As a simple counterexample, consider the subgroups $<r^3,s>$, $<r^3,rs>$ and $<r^3,r^2s>$ of $D_{12}$.

Comment: If P is the direct product of two cyclic groups of order 4, then either P is the only Sylow 2-subgroup of G, or there is another Sylow 2-subgroup of G intersecting P in more than the identity. This basically follows from Sylow's theorem and is a nice example of a group that controls its embeddings very well.  Brauer even classified groups with P as a Sylow 2-subgroup (using more than Sylow theorems).

Comment: It is not enough for the orders of two subgroups to be "different" in order to conclude that their intersection is trivial. You need to use the fact that their orders are *relatively prime*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Firstly, having different orders does not guarantee trivial intersection. For instance in a cyclic group of order $4$, we subgroup of order $2$ and a subgroup of order $4$ will intersect in a subgroup of $2$. *What guarantees trivial intersection is coprime orders.*

**Will two Sylow $p$ subgroups intersect trivially always?**

**Definitely not**. There are plenty of examples, where intersection of two Sylow $p$-Subgroups is not identity.

Firstly, two Sylow $p$-Subgroups intesect trivially if the order of the Sylow is prime. That is, the maximal exponent of $p$ in $|G|$ is $1$. The proof of this fact follows from Lagrange's Theorem. However, I give no guarantee about the converse.

Another related question on when two Sylow Subgroups have trivial intersection is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66796/when-do-sylow-subgroups-have-trivial-intersection).

However, you can still say something about the index of intersection of Sylow Subgroups. For instance, look [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Conjugate-intersection_index_theorem). Related is a fact called Poincare's Theorem which is stated in many forms. One of them is:

> Let $G$ be a finite simple group. Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of $G$. Then the order of $G$ divides $[G:H]!$